# Why am I getting a compile error in this less syntax?

Tags: less

I have generated some background image css code using http://www.patternify.com and added them to a .less file called backgrounds.less. When I save the file and run it through the compiler, it gives me a parse error. I can't seem to resolve these errors.

I have defined each background as a variable and am importing the file into my main styles.less stylesheet using @import "backgrounds.less";

The exact error I get is:

> ParseError: Syntax Error on line 1 in /Volumes/Clients/htdocs/gobet2/less/backgrounds.less:1:145
>   1 @headerbg {background:url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAMAAAADCAYAAABWKLW/AAAAIElEQVQIHWP8DwQMQHD6yVcGBhDn1OMvIOo/A4wB4gAACZQd0vY42rMAAAAASUVORK5CYII=) repeat;}[0m
>
> (This action was triggered by a change to backgrounds.less)

The code is below.

```
@headerbg {background:url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAMAAAADCAYAAABWKLW/AAAAIElEQVQIHWP8DwQMQHD6yVcGBhDn1OMvIOo/A4wB4gAACZQd0vY42rMAAAAASUVORK5CYII=) repeat;}
@navbg {background:url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAMAAAADCAYAAABWKLW/AAAAIUlEQVQIHWN8+fL5fwYgeP/uEQMTjCEoJMfABBIBMUAAADLvDH2vTm1NAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC) repeat;}
@subnavbg {background:url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAMAAAADCAYAAABWKLW/AAAAIElEQVQIHWP8DwQMQHD3zgUGBhDnzu3zIOo/A4wB4gAAA+UdgeoweSoAAAAASUVORK5CYII=) repeat;}
@footerbg {background:url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAMAAAADCAYAAABWKLW/AAAAIElEQVQIHWP8DwQMQPDs2TMGBhDn6dOnIOo/A4wB4gAADVod/MNEi1EAAAAASUVORK5CYII=) repeat;}
@basebg {background:url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAIAAAACCAYAAABytg0kAAAAFElEQVQIHWN8+/b5fwYgYAIRIAAAOj4DxOCeCacAAAAASUVORK5CYII=) repeat;}
```

Any help or solution would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: In less syntax, the @ symbol defines a variable.

For example, elsewhere, I have the following code:

'@lightgrey: rgba(220,219,207,1);'
'@salix: rgba(236,255,195,1);'
'@cramum: rgba(253,255,223,1);'
'@noctis: rgba(23,35,85,1);'
'@arancii: rgba(228,127,23,1);'
'@rivulus: rgba(136,239,255,1);'
'@lightgrey2: rgba(233,233,231,1);'

I don't have any parsing errors there. So, I am not sure what the problem is here.

Comment: Of course, I may be mistaken in my syntax as '@ cramum: rgba(253,255,223,1);' for example, has a different syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A variable can contain a value (not arbitrary rules). So you can define

```
@headerbg: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAMAAAADCAYAAABWKLW/AAAAIElEQVQIHWP8DwQMQHD6yVcGBhDn1OMvIOo/A4wB4gAACZQd0vY42rMAAAAASUVORK5CYII=) repeat;
```

(Note the `:` after the variable name) And later use

```
#header {
  background: @headerbg;
}
```

Comment: Ah, OK. I see my errors now. That solved my problems. Vielen dank Christoph.